# Cross-Compiling Linux Kernel for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation). I'm running on a 32bit Ubuntu installation.

I'm confused by this part: `export CCPREFIX=/path/to/your/compiler/binary/prefix-of-binary-`. I've looked through the `tools` folder I downloaded from github and can't find any binary files. Does anybody know what file the guide is referring to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that you are following gives an example of how to do this. At the top of the document it says `CCPREFIX=/home/me/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-`

In other words, if you cloned `https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools` into the home directory then there would be a `tools` directory there and you should have the same path as the example.